# keyboard events, char counter and textLength prop dilemma

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, keyboard-events

hopefully this is a valid question.

I did a char counter in javascript for a textarea element. Its equivalent to a character counter that limits the amount of text allowed in an input. When a user types in a character, char count goes up and that is shown in a box below so the user knows how many chars he has written so far.

I handled it with both keydown and keypress because the charCode property isn't the same on every browser, mainly Chrome and Opera (didn't check in Safari). When charCode isn't working, keyCode is used. That is not the problem. The problem is in textareaObj.value property.

It seems that when I press a keyboard button, first the keyboard event is handled with the old textareaObj.value value, then the new value is computed, so if I output console.log(textarea.value.length), it shows the old value but in Firefox and Chrome Firebug and Developer tools, the value displayed is the new value.length, the true value of textarea.value.length.

To better explain it, I made a function to handle these events. I put console.log(obj.value.length) in the calling function. The output was the old value but firebug (or firefox web console, or Chrome console) is showing the actual value of the length property. Could anyone explain why this may be happening?

Also, there is a textLength property in the textarea object. It has the same value as textareaObj.value.length but when I try to access it, it is undefined. Why is that?
I looked for textLength in Mozilla Developers page, but it just says what you'd expect, that it hold the length of text, but nothing else.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT:

```
function execute() {
var txtArea = document.getElementById('description');

txtArea.addEventListener('keypress', charCount, false);
txtArea.addEventListener('keydown', charCount, false);
```

}
http://jsfiddle.net/WUJvv/1/

The sample of code is just there for the jsFiddle link.

Here it is. This works on my computer but doesn't work on jsFiddle and i can't get it to work. My apologies. Just do the same thing i did in jsFiddle and it should work.

len variable has to be incremented when user inputs and decrements when user erases characters. It does that very well but if i highlight a large portion of text and erase it all in one, it decrements by 1, because the program sees that my input wasn't a char but the erase button (keyCode 8).

Let's say i input 'This is a sentence' that has 18 chars. I highlight 'sentence' and erase them. That leaves me with 10 chars but txtArea.value.length says 17, because it just sees that i made an input that is not a char, but an erase button (keyCode 8) and just decrements to 17. But if you view the textarea object in Firefox Web Console, you will see that textLength property is 10 and textarea.value is the 'This is a ' (without the 'sentence' part). textLength property would be very useful in this example because it shows the true length of text but its undefined.

I am no expert, but i guess that javascript first enters the function that handles events and then looks what is in the DOM. What actually happens?

Comment: Can you share, ideally in JSFiddle, the code you have so far?

Comment: There is no problem with the code. It works just fine, but i just wanted to know about textLenght and obj.value.length values. I will put the hole code but it would take some time, in about 20 minutes.

Comment: You have tried using the keyup event?

Comment: keyup is the same as keydown only the highlighting part works. but i didn't like that beacuse, if you press and hold the erase button, i doesn't countdown gracefully. If you hold it, it the number stays on the one that you pressed it, and the when you release it, it just sets to the current number of char. I can't really explain vit very well with words.

Comment: I understand what you're saying but I think most (or all) of your issues are occurring because the value hasn't actually changed yet when the keydown or keypress event fires. If you'll notice on these stackoverflow comment boxes; they don't update until keyup, which personally I think is fine.

Comment: So, when keydown fires, the value in textarea is the old one, but when keyup fires, the value is the new one? Would you say that, every time when one works with keyboard event, should always link all three events, not just keypress or keydown or keyup and is that efficient? I didn't try it out with all three beacuse i thought it wouldn't be efficient and might run slow.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: thanks alot. where can i mark your answer as the correct one? I'm not very experienced in stack overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `input` event will get what you want. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3CZu/). It will fire AFTER the value has changed, but continually while the user presses or holds a key.